# Aggregate modeling in domain-driven design

Tags: database-design, domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-sourcing, aggregateroot

This question is in regards to domain-driven design and its related concepts.

In this example, the software is responsible for managing a set of bus routes. A bus route refers to the set of stations where the bus arrives and departs. The schedule represents any route departure along with the actual arrival and departure times specified (the offsets may be different for different departures of the same route). Inventory is managed through a separate set of tables, which defines the physical capacity of any given schedule and its seat assignments. The trip is a booking from one station to another on a particular schedule.

[image: Database Model]

In the diagram that I've attached, there are multiple clusters of tables. Each cluster is supposed to be an aggregate with a root starting at the left -

- Station
- Route with many route stops
- Schedule with many stops
- Inventory with many seat assignments/reservations
- Trip

In a traditional architecture (absent domain-driven design and its notion of aggregates), I would have modified the design to enforce other natural constraints.

For instance, seat reservation should refer to the departure and arrival stop to prevent a seat reservation from a departure station to an arrival station that's not also a stop for that schedule. I chose not to do so here, because it's my understanding that domain-driven design discourages references to non-root entities across aggregates. Since schedule is the aggregate root, that precludes any references to a scheduled stop. The same situation exists for ensuring that a scheduled stop is actually a route stop (although in fairness the current design allows for temporary adjustments of an individual schedule's stops).

Inventory and seat reservation were detached from the schedule aggregate to avoid requiring a transaction across trip and schedule aggregates. By combining capacity and seat reservations in the same aggregate, I can maintain the invariant that number of seats sold is always less than or equal to availability (required by the customer). In the current approach, a reservation would be secured before the trip is confirmed and payment processed. However, that approach still leaves me a reference from the trip aggregate to a seat reservation, which is a non-root entity. The inventory entity is the root in this case because the capacity can be modified at any time by the administrator to either decrease or increase availability.

In short, I'm not convinced that I fully understand how to define aggregate boundaries (perhaps these aggregates are far too small). I'm constantly fighting the urge to consolidate multiple aggregates into a larger one so that the database can help maintain consistency and prevent data corruption. At the same time, in creating smaller aggregates, I'm often tempted to create a reference to a non-root entity. Any advice on tackling these issues would be appreciated!

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to offer specifics as I don't have access to the domain experts. However, there are few things about your approach which don't seem to be right.

1. If you are focusing on domain-driven design then you should really ignore the database structure. It's not relevant at that stage to solving the problem. If anything, thinking in terms of tables will confuse you and lead to a more data first design rather than a domain first design. Think of functionality. What the code needs to do. Rather than the data.
2. It can be helpful to think about the constraints for certain actions (commands). These should be grouped together into an aggregate. I.e. the aggregate should have all it needs to maintain the internal constraints of the operation. This approach can help you find the edges of your aggregates. Other factors to consider are the ubiquitous language. I.e. ensuring that the terms mean the same thing. These are both good ways to find the edges. There is more to finding the aggregates but this will get you started.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I was doing a bit more reading yesterday, and one of the authors raised this same distinction between a traditional data-first design and domain-driven design. I think your comment is starting to clarify a few things for me. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

As Codescribler mentioned, ERD is not relevant here.

There is "Event-Sourcing" tag under your question, so let's look at the problem from this perspective. In even-sourcing we need event streams. Event stream is something that should always be consistent. It seems like an individual bus trip is a good candidate. Before adding another ticket or reservation to a trip you may check if there is sufficient capacity for it.

Other data plays supporting role in this context. It is mostly a reference/read model, so no need to try to model it with DDD and ES for this bounded context.

So, to summarize: I suggest the only aggregate - a particular bus trip.